# How I can split a RTF file

Tags: .net, parsing, rtf

I want to split a RTF file (with C# or VB.Net) in 2 ore more parts by the string `[BreakPage]`. I have for exemple this file, containing a `[BreakPage]`, which needs to be split in 2 parts:

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1251\uc1\deff0\stshfdbch0\stshfloch0\stshfhich0\stshfbi0\deflang1049\deflangfe1049{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fcharset204\fprq2{*\panose
>   02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}{\f38\froman\fcharset0\fprq2
>   Times New Roman;} {\f36\froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Times New Roman
>   CE;}{\f39\froman\fcharset161\fprq2 Times New Roman
>   Greek;}{\f40\froman\fcharset162\fprq2 Times New Roman
>   Tur;}{\f41\froman\fcharset177\fprq2 Times New Roman (Hebrew);}
>   {\f42\froman\fcharset178\fprq2 Times New Roman
>   (Arabic);}{\f43\froman\fcharset186\fprq2 Times New Roman
>   Baltic;}{\f44\froman\fcharset163\fprq2 Times New Roman
>   (Vietnamese);}}{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;\red0\green255\blue255;
>   \red0\green255\blue0;\red255\green0\blue255;\red255\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue128;\red0\green128\blue128;\red0\green128\blue0;\red128\green0\blue128;\red128\green0\blue0;\red128\green128\blue0;
>   \red128\green128\blue128;\red192\green192\blue192;}{\stylesheet{\ql
>   \li0\ri0\widctlpar\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0
>   \fs24\lang1049\langfe1049\cgrid\langnp1049\langfenp1049 \snext0
>   Normal;}{*\cs10 \additive \ssemihidden  Default Paragraph
>   Font;}{*\ts11\tsrowd\trftsWidthB3\trpaddl108\trpaddr108\trpaddfl3\trpaddft3\trpaddfb3\trpaddfr3\trcbpat1\trcfpat1\tscellwidthfts0\tsvertalt\tsbrdrt\tsbrdrl\tsbrdrb\tsbrdrr\tsbrdrdgl\tsbrdrdgr\tsbrdrh\tsbrdrv
>   \ql
>   \li0\ri0\widctlpar\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0
>   \fs20\lang1024\langfe1024\cgrid\langnp1024\langfenp1024 \snext11
>   \ssemihidden Normal
>   Table;}}{*\latentstyles\lsdstimax156\lsdlockeddef0}{*\rsidtbl
>   \rsid2111663\rsid7154806 \rsid15558346}{*\generator Microsoft Word
>   11.0.5604;}{\info{\author Programmer}{\operator
>   Programmer}{\creatim\yr2011\mo8\dy2\hr12\min45}{\revtim\yr2011\mo8\dy5\hr12\min34}{\version3}{\edmins1}{\nofpages1}{\nofwords5}{\nofchars34}{\nofcharsws38}
>   {\vern24689}}\margl1701\margr850\margt1134\margb1134
>   \widowctrl\ftnbj\aenddoc\noxlattoyen\expshrtn\noultrlspc\dntblnsbdb\nospaceforul\hyphcaps0\horzdoc\dghspace120\dgvspace120\dghorigin1701\dgvorigin1984\dghshow0\dgvshow3
>   \jcompress\viewkind1\viewscale100\nolnhtadjtbl\rsidroot15558346
>   \fet0\sectd \linex0\sectdefaultcl\sftnbj
>   {*\pnseclvl1\pnucrm\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta
>   .}}{*\pnseclvl2\pnucltr\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta
>   .}}{*\pnseclvl3 \pndec\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta
>   .}}{*\pnseclvl4\pnlcltr\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta
>   )}}{*\pnseclvl5\pndec\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta
>   )}}{*\pnseclvl6\pnlcltr\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb
>   (}{\pntxta )}} {*\pnseclvl7\pnlcrm\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang
>   {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta
>   )}}{*\pnseclvl8\pnlcltr\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb
>   (}{\pntxta )}}{*\pnseclvl9\pnlcrm\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang
>   {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta )}}\pard\plain  \ql
>   \li0\ri0\nowidctlpar\faauto\rin0\lin0\itap0
>   \fs24\lang1049\langfe1049\cgrid\langnp1049\langfenp1049
>   {\b\insrsid7154806\charrsid7154806 Line 1 \par }{\insrsid7154806  \par
>   }{\i\insrsid7154806\charrsid7154806
>   Line3}{\lang1048\langfe1049\langnp1048\insrsid7154806  \par
>   }{\lang1048\langfe1049\langnp1048\insrsid2111663 [BreakPage] \par
>   }{\insrsid7154806 Line4 \par  \par Line5 \par }}

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that RTF has some (but not necessarily all) formatting information in a global header. In order to split the RTF text so that the results are again valid RTF with formatting applied you essentially need to know where the header information is, and replicate it across a splits.

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Write an RTF parser
2. Use an existing RTF parser

(1) is doable, but will take time. Luckily, RTF parsers already exist, for example [this one on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/nrtftree.aspx).

Alternatively, you can also load the RTF text into a [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx), then search for the split text `"[BreakPage]"` inside the `RichTextBox`, programmatically select the first and second part and retrieve the RTF text using the [`SelectedRtf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedrtf.aspx) property.